# C++ class has no member

Tags: c++

I checked the suggested answer with a similar problem, added a default constructur but the problem remains:

Auto.h:

```
#include <string>

class Auto {
    unsigned int ps;
    std::string type;

public:
    Auto();
    void setPS(unsigned int ps);
    void setType(std::string type);
};
```

and Auto.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include "Auto.h"

// (*)
void Auto::setType(std::string type)
{
}

class Auto {

public:
    
    void setPS(unsigned int ps) {
        ps = ps;
    }

};
```

In Visual Studio, it underlines the `(*)` definition telling me that:
[image]

Is my thinking wrong that it is possible to define the `setType` function outside of the class?

Comment: You have defined Auto twice. IntelliSense is probably detecting your second definition, which doesn’t have a member at all (let alone one called “setType”).

Comment: Delete the `class Auto` stuff in your cpp.  Without that, your code compiles fine with gcc.

Comment: also your cpp file doesn't need the #include directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the default constructor, but you have a class declaration in your cpp file.

Auto.h

```
#include <string>

class Auto 
{
    unsigned int ps;
    std::string type;

public:
    void setPS(unsigned int ps);
    void setType(std::string type);
};
```

Auto.cpp

```
#include "Auto.h"

void Auto::setType(std::string type)
{
    this->type = type;
}

void Auto::setPS(unsigned int ps)
{
    this->ps = ps;
}
```